# Check how many user on a webseite mit signalr and redirect new users

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I'm new to signalr and created a project with this sample to get the number of users on a specific website: [Tutorial](http://www.deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/get-the-number-of-users-that-are-online-using-signalr/1095)

This is running fine. My goal is to access the website only by one user, if a second user want to open the page he should be redirected. How can I do this?

If I check the users on the page and redirect if there are more than one then all users get redirected. Ok that what signalr should do.

```
userActivity.client.updateUsersOnlineCount = function (count) {
// Add the message to the page. 
  $('#usersCount').text(count);
  if (count > 1) { window.document.location.href = "OPL.aspx"; }
};
```

How can I store the `count` in a datatype which I can access from code behind in the .cs? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need two client methods. The `updateUsersOnlineCount` have one job, which is to update users online for all to see. Then you need a second client side method called something like `redirectTheUser` to redirect the user.

In your SignalR hub, you would implement the `OnConnected`, `OnReconnected`, `OnDisconnected` events, to store (keep track of) the connection Ids, and when the count reaches a certain threshold, send the updateUsersOnlineCount to all clients with `Clients.All.updateUsersOnlineCount(msg), but send the message with`Clients.Client(connectionId).redirectTheUser()` for all users above the threshold.

To illustrate:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;  
    _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
    // send to all above threshold
    if(_connections.Count > threshold)
          SendRedirect(_connections.Skip(threshold));
    return base.OnConnected();
}

public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;    
    _connections.Remove(name, Context.ConnectionId);    
    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}

public override Task OnReconnected()
{
    string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;    
    if (!_connections.GetConnections(name).Contains(Context.ConnectionId))
    {
        _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
        // send to all above threshold
        if(_connections.Count > threshold)
            SendRedirect(_connections.Skip(threshold));
    }    
    return base.OnReconnected();
}

private void SendRedirect(IEnumerable<string> connectionIds)
{
    foreach (var connectionId in connectionIds)
    {
        Clients.Client(connectionId).redirectTheUser();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That points me in the right direction. Do I understand right that the hub is for the whole website so it is not possible to check different sites of the same website to allow on each site only one user? thanks

Comment: better said, can I get the page name or QueryString which the user opens? Thanks